# create menu file and make a bash menu list from it

Tags: bash, menu

I'm trying to build a Bash menu to select an option from a series of stations listed in `menulist.txt`:

```
$ cat menulist.txt
Some text to be removed
001A Station1 115 ABC
More text
011C Station2 115 CDE
033F Station3 115 FGH
Even more text, hundreds of lines, some are stations
(...)
```

Problem is I first need to remove several lines of random text from this file and keep only the station lines (`001A`, `011C`, etc.)

This is a large file (more than 500 options after text cleanning). The answer from the menu dialog would have to be only the station code, `001A` or `011C` or some other.

Comment: Does `grep Station menulist.txt` give you only the lines you need?

Comment: Well, it does;) To be more precise, here is an example of the stations list: ftp://uhslc.soest.hawaii.edu/rqds/atlantic/atlantic.lst I will focus on the second column and do 'grep xxx atlantic.lst' Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Otherwise you should make yourself familar with regular expressions.. Something like `^[0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z]` will probably more exactly match your needs.